# django generic view: detail in category

Tags: python, django

I use a generic view to list my categories. 
I would also like to display the title of each items belonging to these categories. 
I understand the principle of ListView and DetailView but what about some details in lists ?

Here are my different files:

**Models.py**

```
class categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class details(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   author = models.CharField(max_length=42)
   category = models.ForeignKey('categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**Views.py**

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    model = categories
    context_object_name = "list_categories"
    template_name='show/index.html'
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

**Index.html**

```
{% load static %}

<p>These is a list of categories</p>

{% for category in list_categories %}
    <div class="article">
       <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>

        {% for title in category.detail %}
            <p> {{title}} </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think maybe you're looking for querying [backwards relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects). It should let you look up details belonging to a category through a property on the category object if my understanding is correct.

Comment: change the category attribute of the details model as below and try again.

category = models.ForeignKey('categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="detail")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first reverse call the `details` with related name i.e "categories".

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<p>These is a list of categories</p>

{% for category in list_categories %}
    <div class="article">
       <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>

        {% for detail in category.categories.all %}
            <p> {{detail.title}} </p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Be careful you must use `all` after reverse all because there could be more then one reverse relation.

Still have any doubts comment it below.

Comment: ok so first category = models.ForeignKey('categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="detail") as Chetan Ganji suggested and then - all

Comment: Yes, when you define a  ForeignKey relationship, a one to many relationship is created between `categories` and `details` additionally one more attribute is added in `categories` by default it is the name of your model with the suffix `_set`  i.e `details_set` but when you specify the `realted_name` then that will be same as your `related_name`, now you can easily call `details` by its related name with object of `categories`. I hope now you understand it more clearly.